# External mapping file to match string texts

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, text, pattern-matching

I have a table of customer feedback (verbatim) that I would like to to 're-map' to the corrected Themes and Sub-Themes based on the keywords in the verbatim.

I would like to maintain an external mapping file that can be updated at any time with the updated mapping. As an example, my external file looks like this, using food data ;)

[image]

The keywords have logical OR/AND conditions, as well as wild card `*` for words like `work*` to map to `working, worked, works` etc.

I would like to map a table like above to my customer feedback table based on the `Category` column.

As an example, if the verbatim is in `Category = Fruit`, and contains the words (`orange` OR `lemon`), then I'd like to update the Themes column to Citrus.

If the theme is Citrus, and verbatim also contains the words (`orange` OR yellow) AND `colour*`, then the Sub-Theme would be `Colour`.

Can someone please advice what the best way to achieve this? And where would be the best place to put the logic for the themes and sub-themes such that there would be minimal changes required for future updates? (if not in this external file).

Would really appreciate your help and feedback!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Has "Category" been determined in some prior step? Or does this re-map process need to output the Category value?  Does "Keyword"  need to allow for "OR" or "AND" or both?  Or just for "OR"  (berry OR berry OR Berry???--not AND)?  The external mapping file would need to ensure the same ThemeKeywordText within each Theme.  e.g. cannot have another row of Citrus with just the value 'lime'  So external mapping seems to be one table for Theme and another table for SubTheme to eliminate duplicated data.

Comment: The Category is also in the Verbatim table (so each customer feedback is associated with a Category which then can be mapped to the external file).
There will be a mixture of both AND/OR in the logic.

Comment: hm... shouldn't be a big problem using SSIS. You could define a dataflow with a C# Transformation (or Source) Component which loads the file into memory and - basing on this modifies your Output...

Comment: Can you share some of the larger picture? What happens after re-map? How is this going to be used?  What about 1)fixes/2)changes/3)additions to the external mapping table ? Do all verbatims get rerun? If not rerun all, are the results coded with the mapping version that was used? Volume issues? Performance issues?